# What documentation tool am I expected to process this with?

Tags: c, documentation-generation

I have a file distributed with an atmel library (`at91lib`), that looks as follows:

```
/**
 \page "AT91 USB device framework"

 AT91 USB %device framework is a device-side USB framework. It enables rapid
 development of USB-compliant class drivers such as the Mass Storage Device
 (MSD) or the Communication Device Class (CDC) and etc.

 This page shows the index to describe the AT91 USB %device framework.
 - USBD: USB Device

 -# "USB Device Framework Architecture"
 -# "USB Device Framework Description"
   -# "Standard USB Structures"
   -# "USBD API"

 [etc]
*/

/**
 \page "USB Device Framework Architecture"

 !!!Framework Architecture

 The following three-tiered structure is used:
 - A #hardware layer# which performs low-level operations on the USB controller.
 - The #USB API# offers hardware-independent methods and structures.
 - The #application layer#, made up of a USB class driver and the user
   application.
*/
```

Obviously, this is some kind of documentation comment system being used to document a directory. It also clearly produces HTML output, as the file contains an HTML image map at some point.

However, the `!!!` doesn't look like doxygen, nor does `#` for linking. Can anyone identify the documentation tool needed to process this to HTML?

Comment: Doxygen does have support for [Markdown](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/markdown.html) as of 1.8.0, supposedly...

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Doesn't resemble markdown either

Comment: Looks like d oxygen try it

Comment: Found a [rendered version](http://elk.informatik.fh-augsburg.de/pub/rtlabor/ti-versuche/SAM7X/sam7x-oocd/atmel/at91sam7x-ek/softpack-1.5/at91lib/at91lib0_dir_description.html)!

Comment: @EdHeal: I already did. Default config had no understanding of either # or !!!, so I assume it's not doxygen input

Comment: Probably needs the configuration to be tweaked

Comment: By examining the Javascripts of the rendered version, my new best guess is that this is [DoxyS](http://www.doxys.dk/doxys_homepage/index.html). Note in particular the [text formatting page](http://www.doxys.dk/doxys_homepage/Screenshots0_page_description.html), which describes how bold is achieved with sandwich #'s.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Yep, just came to the same conclusion. Post that as an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DoxyS

If one goes to the [rendered version of the documentation](http://elk.informatik.fh-augsburg.de/pub/rtlabor/ti-versuche/SAM7X/sam7x-oocd/atmel/at91sam7x-ek/softpack-1.5/at91lib/at91lib0_dir_description.html) and examines the HTML source code (Right-Click -> View Page Source), one sees several linked Javascript files near the top of the HTML.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>../../public_html/softpack-1.5/at91sam7x-ek - at91lib</TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../common/js.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="leftmenu.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The file `../../common/js.js` contains the following within itself:

```
function Body5()
{
document.write("</div>\n");
document.write("</TD><TD class=\"sideIndent\"><img src=\"");
document.write(relPathToCommmon);
document.write("dot.gif\" class=\"sideIndent\"></TD></TR></table>\n");
document.write("</div>\n");
document.write("<div class=\"doxygenFooter\">\n");
document.write("<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 class=\"width\"><TR><TD align=right>\n");
document.write("<a href=\"http://www.doxys.dk\" class=\"generatedDoxygen\" onmouseover=\"overLibGeneratedByDoxyS();return overlib('Generated by DoxyS 0.97<br>Wed Apr 16 16:50 2008');\" onmouseout=\"return nd();\">Generated by DoxyS</A>\n");
document.write("</TD><TD class=\"sideIndent\"><img src=\"");
document.write(relPathToCommmon);
document.write("dot.gif\" class=\"sideIndent\"></TD></TR></table>\n");
document.write("</div>\n");
document.write("</td></tr>\n");
document.write("</table>\n");
}
```

Note in particular the link **`http://www.doxys.dk`** and string **`Generated by DoxyS 0.97<br>Wed Apr 16 16:50 2008`**.